# A short rebus comes here

Tags: rebus

Here is a short rebus that I just created. Let's see if you can solve it.
[image: rebus]

Hint

> it is an old proverb

Comment: Don't take pills at the beach, y'all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it

> One swallow doesn't make a summer

Comment: Correct answer 

Answer (score 1):

A very rude answer:

> If the lady takes the pill, there will be no kids to take to the beach.

Comment: Nope. Too literal.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stretch but

> You shouldn't eat before you swim? Because the picture shows the girl eating (pills) and then the beach picture is crossed out. Normally adults swim at the beach.

Comment: Wrong answer. But the right amount of abstract thinking :)

Comment: Hmm, if I want to give another answer then should I edit the current one or write another separate answer? Or do I get only one try?

Comment: Well u can always edit your answer or even post a new one. This site does not limit u to only 1 answer try per question :) @R.D

Comment: I see. I will give it another try.